# How to install some VPN in Linux Mint

Tags: vpn

Which one and how can I install a VPN service on Linux Mint to access resources (`npm` packages install, Docker, and so on) not accessible from my country?

In Windows I use `Psiphon`, but I can't find anything similar for Linux.

Comment: Is `tor` accessible to you?

Comment: @davidt930, yes Tor browser work for me

Comment: I have downloaded Tor browser from Tor project website, but wen I try to install from Tor browser launcher (installed from repo) it give 404 error.

Comment: TOR Bundle doesn't require installation. Simply download and extract the file somewhere. The simply run "start tor..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a `tor` client. You can install it from package manager. Since you can't install it from package manager and you already have `Tor Browser`, you can use `tor` client that is packaged with the `Tor Browser`. Locate the `tor` binary and open a terminal and run

```
/<somepath>/tor
```

This should establish a connection with `tor` nodes and open a `socks5` proxy listening on port `9050`(if `tor` is already running you'll get a different `socks5` port).

Now all you'll have to do is route your computers internet traffic through `socks` proxy. To do this goto `start menu`->`network`->`network proxy` -> `manual`. Then in the field `socks host` enter `localhost` and `9050`.

Here is a screenshot [image: Network Manager]

Note: please don't use tor proxy with `chrome` or `firefox`.

Since you already use `psiphon` you can look for `psiphon` client for `Linux`[2].

[2] https://github.com/Psiphon-Labs/psiphon-tunnel-core-binaries

Comment: Ok, I had followed yours tips and it work but, I had to configure socket proxy on browser and terminal ,although is configured in networks setting like you indicated.

Comment: @Francisco It seems that `Network Manager` is using `gsettings` to set up proxy through `socks5` port. I didn't realize this but it seems that you need `gui` applications to restart before they can use proxy set by `gsettings`. This is also true for `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Also do not use `tor` with `chrome` or `firefox`. It may give you a false sense of anonymity.

Comment: thank you for suggestions. Really I need only for terminal, in case of web browsing I can use downloaded version of tor browser. I give the question as closed, and your answer accepted!!!